# Replace newlines with br but ignore newlines after h1 in PHP

Tags: php, newline

Is it possible to replace newlines with the `<br>` tag, but to ignore newlines that follow a `</h1>` tag?

So for example I want to change this block:

```
<h1>Test</h1> \n some test here \n and here
```

To this:

```
<h1>Test</h1> some test here <br /> and here
```

Comment: Why would you have that kind of code at the first place? It just seems that your orginal situation itself is a problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$subject = "<h1>hithere</h1>\nbut this other\nnewline should be replaced.";
$new = preg_replace("/(?<!h1\>)\n/","<br/>",$subject);
echo $new;

// results in:
// <h1>hithere</h1>
// but this other<br/>newline should be replaced.
```

Should work. This says \n not preceeded immediately by h1>

Answer (score 1):

Using string functions instead of regular expressions, and assuming the `</h1>` tag can be anywhere on the line (instead of just before the newline):

```
$lines=file($fn);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
  if (stristr("$line", "</h1>") == FALSE) {
    $line = str_replace("\n", "<br />", $line);
  }
  echo $line;
}
```

which, for your example, results in:

`<h1>`Test`</h1>`
some test here `<br />`and here`<br />`